# Error: 0 Cannot open file for writing log on joomla backend

Tags: php, joomla

i have set the folder path for tmp folder and log folder as below

```
public $log_path = '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/tmp';
```

and i have created a test.php on my site to get the actual path which gives me

```
acutal path = " /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs"
```

I have given 777 folder permission for both tmp folder and logs folder but still i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in your `test.php`:

```
<?php 
 $path = getcwd();
 echo "Your Absoluthe Path is: ";
 echo $path;
 ?>
```

It will give you absolute path which should be prefixed in log & tmp paths.

Comment: i have already did it which i have posted above and its giving me 
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs